# Return a specific type from a list

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a component-entity system for a game and I hit a bit of a road block. I have a `List<Component>` derived class call ComponentList that contains all the components for an Entity. I also have a method that returns a component called GetComponent. It does this by a string name.

```
    public Component GetComponent(string name)
    {
        foreach (var c in this)
        {
            if (c.Name == name)
                return c;
        }
        throw new Exception("Component " + name + " does not exist.");
    }
```

However, when deriving a class from Component, sticking it into the ComponentList, then pulling it back out, I have to cast in to that type, which is a bit inconvenient.

```
TestComponent t1 = (TestComponent)Entity.ComponentList.GetComponent("Test1");
```

I know there is some special, magic way to take a type with < T > but I'm not sure how to use it or, if it even applicable to this situation. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
public T GetComponent<T>(string name) where T : Component
{
    var result = this.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == name);
    if( result == null )
        throw new Exception("Component " + name + " does not exist.");
    return (T) result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var testComponent = componentFactory.GetComponent<TestComponent>("Test1");
```

The language feature enabling this is called `generics` and you can read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (and many, many other places; just google for "generics C#")

Comment: It gives me this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication1.Component' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Right, missed a cast. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain a bit about how this works or, at least shoot me a page explaining the whole <T> dealio? I'm not even sure what it's called. :(

Comment: The is an abundance of online resources explaining "generics", just google a bit and you will be rewarded.

Comment: Thank you! I never knew about them but, they are really helpful when you need to do things with types. Thanks alot for your help!